# How to generate a PDF file from a custom module Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to generate a PDF file with a custom module.

When I'm generating a PDF file it's outputting the file below.

[image: PDF invoice output]

I want to display a PDF without the header, footer or any of those codes showing on the right side of the page.

This is what i have so far, a class with the following code:

```
<?php

class HTMLTemplatePrintLabelPdf extends HTMLTemplate
{
public $custom_model;

public function __construct($custom_object, $smarty)
{
    $this->custom_model = $custom_object;
    $this->smarty = $smarty;
    
  
}

/**
 * Returns the template's HTML content
 * @return string HTML content
 */
public function getContent()
{
    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'custom_model' => $this->custom_model,
    ));

    return $this->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'pancorderlabel/pdf/printlabel.tpl');
}

public function getLogo()
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns the template filename
 * @return string filename
 */
public function getFilename()
{
    return 'pdf/printlabel.pdf';
}

/**
 * Returns the template filename when using bulk rendering
 * @return string filename
 */
public function getBulkFilename()
{
    return 'pdf/printlabel.pdf';
}
}
```

And on my module main file at hookDisplayAdminOrdeMain, a submit button like this:

```
$pdf = new PDF($custom_object, 'PrintLabelPdf', Context::getContext()->smarty);
$pdf->render();
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I understand correctly you want to generate a pdf without header or footer.
Here are the steps to follow to achieve this:

To start, you have to override the **classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php** file (therefore create **override/classes/pdf/PDFPrintLabelGenerator.php**) and modify the header() and footer() functions like this :

```
<?php

/**
 * @since 1.5
 */

class PDFPrintLabelGenerator extends PDFGeneratorCore 
{

  /**
 * @see TCPDF::Header()
 */
public function Header()
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * @see TCPDF::Footer()
 */
public function Footer()
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Write a PDF page.
 */
public function writePage()
{
    $this->setMargins(0, 0, 0);
    $this->AddPage();
    $this->writeHTML($this->content, true, false, true, false, '');
}
```

Now, you want only your custom document to use **override/classee/pdf/PDFPrintLabelGenerator.php** in order to keep the header and the footer on the other documents (invoices for example) it is therefore necessary to override **classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php** (therefore create **override/classes/pdf/PDFPrintLabelCore.php** extends ) and change its constructor to instantiate the correct class:

```
public function __construct($objects, $template, $smarty, $orientation = 'P')
{
    $this->pdf_renderer = new PDFPrintLabelGenerator((bool) Configuration::get('PS_PDF_USE_CACHE'), $orientation);
    $this->template = $template;

    $this->smarty = clone $smarty;
    $this->smarty->escape_html = false;

    $original_lazy_register = SmartyLazyRegister::getInstance($smarty);

    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'function', 'convertPrice', array('Product', 'convertPrice'), true, $original_lazy_register);
    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'function', 'convertPriceWithCurrency', array('Product', 'convertPriceWithCurrency'), true, $original_lazy_register);
    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'function', 'displayWtPrice', array('Product', 'displayWtPrice'), true, $original_lazy_register);
    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'function', 'displayWtPriceWithCurrency', array('Product', 'displayWtPriceWithCurrency'), true, $original_lazy_register);
    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'function', 'displayPrice', array('Tools', 'displayPriceSmarty'), true, $original_lazy_register);
    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'modifier', 'convertAndFormatPrice', array('Product', 'convertAndFormatPrice'), true, $original_lazy_register); // used twice
    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'function', 'displayAddressDetail', array('AddressFormat', 'generateAddressSmarty'), true, $original_lazy_register);
    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'function', 'getWidthSize', array('Image', 'getWidth'), true, $original_lazy_register);
    smartyRegisterFunction($this->smarty, 'function', 'getHeightSize', array('Image', 'getHeight'), true, $original_lazy_register);

    $this->objects = $objects;
    if (!($objects instanceof Iterator) && !is_array($objects)) {
        $this->objects = array($objects);
    }

    if (count($this->objects) > 1) { // when bulk mode only
        $this->send_bulk_flag = true;
    }
}
```

Finally a last override so that the controller can generate your custom PDF using **override/classes/pdf/PDFPrintLabelGenerator.php**

So in **override/controllers/admin/AdminPdfController.php**:

```
<?php
require(_PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_ . "/" . "classes" . "/" . "pdf" . "/" . "PDFPrintLabelGenerator.php");

    public function MyCustomPdf($object, $template)
    {
        $pdf = new PDFPrintLabelGenerator($object, $template, Context::getContext()->smarty);
        $pdf->render();
    }

    public function generateMyCustomPdf($id_order)
    {
      // do your stuff here
      $this->MyCustomPdf($order_invoice_collection,PDF::TEMPLATE_CUSTOM);
    }
```

I assumed you already had a custom template

I am aware that I did not use a module but for me, this is the easiest way to generate a custom PDF without header or footer